# Sharepoint 2013 - Create custom page with code behind

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, asp.net, aspx

I have many event receivers and, on error, I want to redirect to a custom page that will manage those errors.

I know that I can create a custom page per Event Receiver with the creation of Mapped Folder in Visual Studio, but, I want a single page that'll deal with any of my ER.

In addition of that, this page must have a code-behind because I want to manage the error sent by the ER (via a redirection), using the Response.Querystring property of the page.

Is there any way to create a custom aspx page with code behind at the root of the site collection ?

Thanks for your answer.

Edit (2016-06-27): I followed the tutorial indicated below, but I have an error when I deploy my solution: `Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Error: Cannot find this file specified in the manifest file: SP2013_ErrorPage.dll`

I adapted the Package.Template.xml like that for my solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Assemblies>
<Assembly Location="SP2013_ErrorPage.dll"
          DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache">
  <SafeControls>
    <SafeControl Assembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
                 Namespace="SP2013_ErrorPage"
                 TypeName="ErrorPageTemplate"
                 Safe="True"/>
  </SafeControls>
</Assembly>
</Assemblies>
</Solution>
```

Comment: Write a Visual Web Part if you want code behind and drop it on your ErrorHandling page.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to finalize that which kind of page do you need like `Application Page` or `Site Page`?

Using the most basic definition, a `site page` is **customizable** by an end user while an `application page` **is not**.  That means that a user can pop open SharePoint Designer 2010 and make changes to a site page, but they cannot do this with an application page.  So, what do we mean by “customizable”?  When we open SharePoint Designer 2010 and make changes to a site page, those changes are stored in the database.  The next time we request the page, the page is loaded from the database.  There are more differences than this, but the key difference is really the ability to customize a page.

You can get more details from below link.

[Creating a SharePoint Site Page With Code-Behind Using Visual Studio 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2010/06/28/creating-a-sharepoint-site-page-with-code-behind-using-visual-studio-2010/)

Comment: Are you able to create page from code behind? Is above given answer helps you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will investigate on that and return as soon as possible to give you a answer. Is the process the same for VS2015 and Sharepoint 2013 ?

Comment: Yes there will be same process.

Comment: I tried it for SP2013 & VS2013. It worked fine for me.

Comment: So, I followed the tutorial but, when I deploy, I encounter an error: "Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Error: Cannot find this file specified in the manifest file: SP2013_ErrorPage.dll". That is logic I think because the file doesn't exist yet in the GAC

Comment: (For more info, my project is named SP2013_ErrorPage instead of SampleToDeployAPage). I think the error is linked with the Package.Template.xml file, the deploy failed when I add content

Comment: Kindly check the answer here for resolution...https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0aa9ba9f-c6ec-49dc-b258-098ba38ad9de/error-cannot-find-this-file-specified-in-the-manifest-file?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: Ho, ok, thanks for the tip, I believed the deploy would doing it all by itself...

Comment: That must be a case for you. Glad to help you... :)

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work, I added the dll to the GAC via gacutil but I still doesn't see the dll in GAC

Comment: I even tried to install it via Powershell: `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.EnterpriseServices") | Out-Null 
[System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish] $publish = new-object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish
$publish.GacInstall("F:\Développements\SP2013_PageError\SP2013_PageError\bin\x64\Release\SP2013_PageError.dll")` but still no luck